# Android USB port suddenly functional

Tags: usb, samsung-droid-charge, usb-storage

I did system update on my android device and after some days, i discovered my phone which used to fully charge under two hours could only charge around 10% in an hour. I couldn't connect via the USB to the computer anymore. 
So today after i made up my mind i was going to take it to a repairer, everything suddenly returned to normal. I don't know how i can explain that. Should i still take it there or keep using it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would continue using it.

1. Could of just been a setting that went unnoticed
2. Could of been a glitch in the actual wire (maybe the connectors on eac end or the wire itself)

There's a number of things it may of been but if it's working fine now, I'd recommend just using it.  "If it ain't broke don't fix it".